# What are the significant assumptions in the Inflation theory?

Tags: cosmological-inflation

I've tried looking for it,
but there doesn't seem to be any assumption since the theory is based on how things move apart from each other so I can't seem to see assumptions.

Comment: This question has also been posted and answered on [Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21249/10589)

Comment: @DhruvSaxena Yeah, I posted it in two Communities. I already got my answer there

Comment: It's just that people prefer the overlapping questions to be posted on not more than one Stack Exchange at a time. The intent of the comment was to keep the future visitors informed so that they may add, if they wish to, any other information which isn't a part of the answer you've received so far :)